# Points to line in ArcGIS Desktop says Not enough points to create a line for value <value>?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a set of points that I want to connect according to their ids. To do so I chose the tool 'Points to line' of ArcGIS. Unfortunatly when I execute the script,  it gives this error :

```
Not enough points to create a line for value <value>.
```

What is the origin of the error and what should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Points To Line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277706/points-to-line-is-not-working) documentation:

> Line feature will not be written to the output if they are made up of
>   less than two vertices.

I suspect that if you look at the frequency of Line_Field values you will find that at least one of them occurs only once.

Also, as commented by @Vince:

> Not only does there need to be more than one vertex, but they must
>   also be at least the minimum XY coordinate tolerance apart, so this
>   could be a coordinate reference issue as well.

Comment: Not only does there need to be more than one vertex, but they must also be at least the minimum XY coordinate tolerance apart, so this could be a coordinate reference issue as well.

Comment: And these points are to be within environment extent. -1.